# Excel Formula To Return No If No Exists in List

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, excel-2013

I thought a `Match()` function would work here, but this is not my desired results.  Here is a sample Data Set

```
userID  OnTime
5   yes
5   yes
5   yes
5   yes
5   yes
5   no
3   yes
3   no
3   yes
3   yes
3   yes
3   yes
1   yes
1   yes
1   yes
1   yes
1   yes
1   yes
1   yes
```

Now what I am after is for each unique userID if a `NO` exists, then return no, if there is not a `No` value in the list for that userID return yes

So my desired returned result is

```
5  no
3  no
1  yes
```

I tried this `Match()` formula, but it is returning an `#N/A` error -

```
=MATCH(E2,B2:B7,1)
```

What would be a proper formula to return my desired results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use countifs:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,E2,B:B,"no"),"no","yes")
```

[image]

Comment: Bah! Beat me by a second. You're quick!

Comment: I'm wondering, and it'd be a different question, how you could do a formula if you didn't know it was "yes" and "no".  Say OP just wanted to return "yes" if the values were all the same, per number, and "no" if they were different?

Comment: If you didn't know at least one, a helper column is the only way.  where you would compare the countifs() of the two columns to the COUNTIF() of the first.

Comment: For BruceWayne's question couldn't you find the first value for each number by using an index/match or vlookup, then use that value in the countif?